# HDD needle speed

Tags: hard-drive

Does anybody know the "physical speed" of an average HDD Needle?

No, I'm not talking about writing or reading speeds. I mean the actual movement speed of the needle used in regular commercially available hard-drives, as in units of m/s or km/h.

This might be a really stupid question but it's been in my head for the last 30 minutes and I couldn't find anything about this topic online.

Comment: Does this answer the question? https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/326567/what-is-the-speed-of-hard-disk-actuator-arm _(it's a magnetic read/write head so I searched for "hdd read head movement speed", I don't think anybody else [seriously](https://xkcd.com/378/) calls it a needle)_

Comment: The head (there is no needle) actually moves fairly slowly as it just needs to position itself over the spinning platter.  Im not sure how fast this is.  The speed that the platter moves under the head can be calculated.  This is all extremely spproximate and math is not my strong point but - on a 3.5" disk the platter size will be about 85mm in diameter, so an outer circumference of  say 255mm. If we assume a rotation speed of 5200 rpm we get a speed of **about 82 km/h** - 0.255m *5400rpm*60 minutes....

Comment: 2.5 inch drives will be slower  7200 rpm drives faster and the average speed will be slower (in my experience about half the speed)  because this assumes data near the outermost part of the disk.

Comment: I was erong about the arm movement. According to https://blog.seagate.com/business/how-fast-is-a-hard-drive-actuator-arm-the-slow-mo-guys-know/ it moves about 22* on 1/4 second, so 88 times per second.  Ignoring its moving in an arc and not all the way to the center if the disk  the head itself is moving at about 42mm * 22 * 4 per second which works out to about **13km / h.**

Comment: Again, all very  very approx "back of an envelope calcs" and my math might be wrong (hence its a comment not an answer.)

Comment: The link by @user1686 is good but lacks details.  I've studied the details of a full-size (floor standing) drive.  The head speed can have three phases: acceleration, constant velocity, and deceleration.  Short seeks only do acceleration & deceleration.  If the seek is long enough, then the actuator can accelerate to full velocity.  BTW the math I've seen used to justify "short stroking" a HDD is all wrong because they assume a fixed & constant speed for any/every seek distance.  That could be true for a stepper motor (now obsolete), but not a voice coil.